# Pandas str.count()

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 2 columns and I am trying to create a third column that counts the number of occurrences of the first column in the second.

sample_df =

```
Object  Text
Banana  Banana Banana Banana
Banana  Apple Apple Apple
Apple   Banana Apple
```

Right now I am trying the below code:

```
sample_df['Mentions'] = sample_df['Text'].count(sample_df['Object'])
```

Which yields the below error:

```
AttributeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-65-c9ae4ce28088> in <module>()
----> 1 sample_df['Mentions'] = sample_df['Text'].count(sample_df['Object'])

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/series.pyc in count(self, 
level)
1177             level = self.index._get_level_number(level)
1178 
-> 1179         lev = self.index.levels[level]
1180         lab = np.array(self.index.labels[level], subok=False, copy=True)
1181 

AttributeError: 'RangeIndex' object has no attribute 'levels'
```

Answer (score 3):

If you read the documentation of [**`pd.Series.count`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.Series.count.html), you will see it does not do what you think it does:

> **`Series.count(level=None)`**
>
> Return number of non-NA/null observations in the Series

You've provided a pandas Series as the level argument, which is invalid, and is why you are getting the error.  For your use, try this instead:

```
df['counter'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.Text.count(x.Object), axis=1)

   Object                  Text  counter
0  Banana  Banana Banana Banana        3
1  Banana     Apple Apple Apple        0
2   Apple          Banana Apple        1
```

If you care about performance, you can also use a simple list comprehension here:

```
df['counter'] = [i.count(j) for i, j in zip(df.Text, df.Object)]
```

***Timings (Use the list comprehension :D)***

```
df = pd.concat([df]*10000)

%timeit df.apply(lambda x: x.Text.count(x.Object), axis=1)
1.14 s ± 14.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit [i.count(j) for i, j in zip(df.Text, df.Object)]
6.71 ms ± 25 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter
def count(row):
    temp=row[1].split(' ')
    d=Counter(temp)
    return d[row[0]]
df['Mentions']=df.apply(lambda x: count(x),axis=1)
print(df)

    Object      Text                  Mentions
0   Banana  Banana Banana Banana    3
1   Banana  Apple Apple Apple       0
2   Apple   Banana Apple            1
```